# Kotlin transform Set elements and keep Set?

Tags: kotlin, set

Is there a way to `.map` each element in `Set` and keep `Set` as output?

Now when I call:

```kotlin
val result: List<String> = setOf("b", "a", "z").map { "${it}.b" }
```

the result is `List`, but I want to have the result as a `Set` without additional conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fold

```
val result: Set<String> = setOf("b", "a", "z").fold(mutableSetOf()) { set, it ->
        set += "${it}.b" 
        set
    }
```